# Advice on porting nested routines to OpenACC

Tags: fortran, subroutine, openacc

I am quite new to OpenACC and I'd like to port a quite big Fortran code to GPUs. At present, the code is hybrid MPI and OpenMP, but we'd like to take advantage of GPUs on some big machines. The compiler I'll use for this is nvfortran. The code evolves some 3D quantities, given by 3D arrays with indexes `(i1,i2,i3)`, in time. For this, we perform a lot of different operations on the arrays. An important point is that we always perform operations on only one coordinate at a time, we do not mix coordinates, i.e., we can have

```
A(i1,i2,i3) = B(i1+1,i2,i3) + C(i1-1,i2,i3)
!OR
A(i1,i2,i3) = B(i1,i2+1,i3) + C(i1,i2-1,i3)
```

but we don't have `A(i1,i2,i3) = B(i1+1,i2,i3) + C(i1,i2-1,i3)`. This is important because, to take advantage of some optimizations, we: first performs all operations along the first coordinate (i1); second we transpose everything such that we have the variables in the order `(i2,i1,i3)`; third we perform all operations along i2; fourth we transpose the variables to have the order `(i3,i1,i2)`; fifth we perform operations along i3; and finally we transpose everything back to `(i1,i2,i3)`.

The logic of the code is the following:

```
integer :: m1,n1,m2,n2,m3,n3
integer :: m1c,n1c,m2c,n2c,m3c,n3c
integer :: Nmax, nchunks, ichunk
double precision, allocatable(:,:,:) :: A,B,C
double precision, allocatable(:,:,:) :: sliceA, sliceB, sliceC
!
allocate(A(m1:n1,m2:n2,m3:n3),B(m1:n1,m2:n2,m3:n3),C(m1:n1,m2:n2,m3:n3))
... ! A and B are initialized
! Get the number of chunks
call getChunkSize(Nmax,m1,n1,m2,n2,m3,n3,1,m2c,n2c,m3c,n3c,nchunks)
! Start parallel OMP region
!$OMP PARALLEL DEFAULT(SHARED), &
!$OMP          PRIVATE(sliceA,sliceB,sliceC, &
!$OMP                  m2c, n2c, m3c, n3c, &
!$OMP                  ichunk)
... ! Some stuff
!$OMP DO
do ichunk=1,nchunks
  ! Get indexes m2c,n2c,m3c,n3c
  call getChunkSize(Nmax,m1,n1,m2,n2,m3,n3,ichunk,m2c,n2c,m3c,n3c)
  !
  allocate(sliceA(m1:n1,m2c:n2c,m3c:n3c),sliceB(m1:n1,m2c:n2c,m3c:n3c),sliceC(m1:n1,m2c:n2c,m3c:n3c))
  sliceA(:,:,:) = A(m1:n1,m2c:n2c,m3c:n3c)
  sliceB(:,:,:) = B(m1:n1,m2c:n2c,m3c:n3c)
  !
  call operations(sliceA,sliceB,sliceC)
  !
  C(m1:n1,m2c:n2c,m3c:n3c) = sliceC(:,:,:)
  deallocate(sliceA,sliceB,sliceC)
end do
!$OMP END DO
... ! Some other stuff
!$OMP END PARALLEL
!
! REPEAT the same logic, but for slice(m2:n2,m1c:n1c,m3c:n3c) and for slice(m3:n3,m1c:n1c,m2c:n2c)
```

Here, `Nmax` is an integer variable, input of the code, that states the maximum number of elements of the arrays sliceA, sliceB, and sliceC, used to improve cache performances of the code. What we want is to split the big arrays A, B, and C in nchunks pieces (chunks), each piece (chunk) with a number of elements smaller or equal to Nmax. For this, we first use the routine `getChunkSize` to get nchunks, such that `nchunks*(n1-m1+1)*(n2c-m2c+1)*(n3c-m3c+1) = (n1-m1+1)*(n2-m2+1)*(n3-m3+1)` and `(n1-m1+1)*(n2c-m2c+1)*(n3c-m3c+1)<Nmax`.
We then have a loop over nchunks, parallelized with OMP, such that each thread takes a slice of the arrays A, B, and C, and performs some operations with the routine `operations`. The results, that the routine `operations` returns in `sliceC` are then copied to the big array C.
A similar task is then performed along the two other coordinates, after transposing the arrays such that the first index is always the one along which we operate.

Two notable examples are with `Nmax=(n1-m1+1)*(n2-m2+1)*(n3-m3+1)`, for which we obviously have `nchunks=1` (one single chunk, containing the full arrays), and with `Nmax=n1-m1+1`, for which we have `nchunks=(n2-m2+1)*(n3-m3+1)` (one single "line" m1:n1 for each slice).

The routine `operations` calls some other routines to perform many operations on the arrays sliceA and sliceB to produce sliceC. These other routines contains, among other things, loops in the form

```
do i3=m3c,n3c
  do i2=m2c,n2c
    do i1=m1,n1
      sliceC(i1,i2,i3) = ...
    end do
  end do
end do
```

where the operations, as stated above, always have the same indexes i2 and i3 on the left and on the right of the statement, only i1 can differ (generally we can use i1-2, i1-1, i1, i1+1, and i1+2).

Here is my question: what would be the best approach to parallelize with OpenACC directives this code? I see two possibilities:

1. I keep the same logic, and parallelize the external loop (the one over chunks) over the different gangs, while I parallelize the inner loops in the subroutines (the triple loops over i3,i2,i1) over workers and vectors. In this case, how should I define the `operations` routine with acc? Moreover, what would be the ideal value for `Nmax` (e.g., should I try to have the resulting nchunks a multiple of the number of gangs available on the GPU)?
2. I set `Nmax=(n1-m1+1)*(n2-m2+1)*(n3-m3+1)` in the input file (the OpenMP version should remain the same, the code should work both on CPUs and on GPUs, I cannot break the OpenMP functionality, although I can introduce some preprocessing flag to avoid copying data from A to sliceA - and similarly for the other variables - when OpenACC is active), such that I do not have an external loop (nchunks=1), and I apply all the GPU parallelization on the inner loops only.

What would be the benefits/disadvantages of the two strategies? Is one definitely better than the other? Are there other possibilities?
One note: in the routine `operations` I have to allocate/deallocate several other arrays of size `(m1:n1,m2c:n2c,m3c:n3c)`.

Any advice on this subject would be highly appreciated. If you can provide real examples and/or the syntax  for the outer loop (in particular what acc directive I should use for defining the `operations` routine), even better (I didn't find a good tutorial/book explaining in detail how the !$acc routine works)!

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour] around the site. When you are already using OpenMP for threads, why not also use it for the accelerators? It's up to you, of course. The issues will be similar.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give a look! Concerning OpenMP vs OpenACC, I was wondering which one would be better, and I've been suggested that, for the machines I have access to, OpenACC should deliver some better performances than OpenMP. In the end it is mostly a matter of performances vs portability, and it seems that for my needs OpenACC would be better (I was even thinking of implementing both with some preprocessing flags).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you'd get rid of the chunking and operate directly on the full A, B, and C arrays.  You could set the number of chunks to 1, but then you'll suffer the overhead of having to copy the slices to the device each time the routine is called.

I generally advise the strategy of a top-down approach for data and bottom-up for compute.  Meaning move your data regions early in the program, preferably using a "enter data create" just after the array allocation, so the lifetime and scope of the arrays are the same on the host and device.  Then use the "update" directive to synchronize the host and device copies of the array when necessary.  Data movement is often one of the biggest performance bottle-necks so minimizing this critical.

While you don't show the code for "operations", you'll likely want to put the OpenACC parallel compute regions around the loops in this routine.  If there are multiple loops, then you'll use multiple compute regions.

"acc routine" tells the compiler to create a device callable version of the routine.  It needs to be visible to both the caller and the callee so usually placed in the header section of the routine's definition in a module or interface.  If there isn't an interface, i.e. F77-style, then you need it twice.  Once in the routine's definition so a device version is compiled, and once in the caller's definition so it's declared and the compiler knows that a device version is available.  For the declaration, the form "acc routine(routine_name)" would be used.

If you have parallelizable loops inside the routines themselves, then you may opt to use "routine vector", meaning that routine will have a vector level parallel loop inside the routine.  The caller would then have a "gang" parallel loop.

For OpenACC vs OpenMP, it's largely user preference at this point and my advice above applies both and GPU programming in general.

OpenMP's data management directives, i.e. "target data", are basically the same as OpenACC, just different syntax.

For compute, OpenMP has two methods, "target teams distribute parallel do" and "target teams loop".  "distribute" has more flexibility on the types constructs that can be used on the device, but incurs more overhead.  "loop" is more restrictive but often more performant (at least with nvfortran).  "loop" is basically the same as OpenACC's "parallel" construct.

There is one key difference in that OpenMP doesn't have a way to expose parallelism inside of device routines.  So if you do want to use "routine vector", then you'll want to stick with OpenACC.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! If I understand it correctly, using the bottom-up strategy for computations means that I don't try to do cache management explicitly, but I let the compiler doing it. One thing that I didn't mention is that I will have to do the "memory transpose" anyway (for step2 and step3), because all routines in `operations` operate along the first dimension only. Thus, my "strategy 1" would allow doing the different transpose of each chunk asynchronously, and operate on the chunk as soon as it is ready. Would the bottom-up strategy still be preferable?

Comment: While NVIDIA GPUs do have software managed caching, the hardware managed caching is quite good, so using "shared" memory isn't often needed any longer.  The compiler will try to use shared memory for gang private arrays and the user can use the "cache" directive, but again it's rare that it's needed.

Comment: By "bottom-up", I'm meaning that you want to move the compute regions to the lower level parallel loops.  GPUs are best with data parallelism (i.e. each thread acting on a element of as the same array or arrays) as opposed concurrency which is what you're doing with the blocking algorithm.  Not to say that you couldn't do this, and I don't know your code, but if you keep what you have, you'll want to make sure the "chunk" loop uses only a "gang" schedule.  Then parallelize the inner data parallel loops in "operation" using "vector", which means using "routine vector".

Comment: The number of chunks would then be the number of streaming multiprocessors (SM) on the GPU multiplied by 32 (assuming an occupancy of 50% or more).

Comment: For the "slice" arrays, I'd hoist the allocation to before the start of the chunk loop, and then privatize them via a "private" clause.  While you can do allocation on the device, it can be slow and the heap size is very small.  Granted, this can increased via the environment variable "NV_ACC_CUDA_HEAPSIZE", but is still better to privatize the arrays.

Comment: Thank you for all this information! I see that the two different approaches can lead to quite dramatic behaviours. It is hard to predict which approach would be better. With the concurrency approach (approach 1 above) it would be much easier to do data management and avoid copies of data from the host to the device. On the other hand, it would require more operations with low parallelism on the device. Time to start coding and test the results!